# Z-index not working (yes, the position is set)

Tags: css

I can't seem to get z-index working properly. There are a lot of StackOverflow questions about this, but in most of them, the issue is that position is not set. I have set position, yet I still cannot get it to work. I would like the box with the text to be on top of the grey bar.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/8sfz5wrj/1/

```
.pictures{
    height: 45vh;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.main{
    margin-top: -30vh !important;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-blue.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/personal-site-page.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="mdl-layout">
        <div class="pictures"></div>
        <div class="mdl-layout__content">
            <div class="main mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col"></div>
                <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-shadow--4dp">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>
                        Cillum dolor esse sit incididunt velit eiusmod magna ad nostrud officia aute dolor dolor. Magna esse ullamco pariatur adipisicing consectetur eu commodo officia. Ex cillum consequat mollit minim elit est deserunt occaecat nisi amet. Quis aliqua nostrud Lorem occaecat sunt. Eiusmod quis amet ullamco aliquip dolore ut incididunt duis adipisicing. Elit consequat nisi eiusmod aute ipsum sunt veniam do est. Occaecat mollit aliquip ut proident consectetur amet ex dolore consectetur aliqua elit.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Cillum dolor esse sit incididunt velit eiusmod magna ad nostrud officia aute dolor dolor. Magna esse ullamco pariatur adipisicing consectetur eu commodo officia. Ex cillum consequat mollit minim elit est deserunt occaecat nisi amet. Quis aliqua nostrud Lorem occaecat sunt. Eiusmod quis amet ullamco aliquip dolore ut incididunt duis adipisicing. Elit consequat nisi eiusmod aute ipsum sunt veniam do est. Occaecat mollit aliquip ut proident consectetur amet ex dolore consectetur aliqua elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` with `position: relative` work best with elements next to each other

You then need to set the z-index on the most parent `div` of your text (the one with `mdi-layout__content` class in this case), which is next to the pictures `div`

```css
.pictures {
 height: 45vh;
 background-color: gray;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
}
.mdl-layout__content {
    margin-top: -30vh !important;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-blue.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/personal-site-page.css" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="mdl-layout">
  <div class="pictures"></div>
  <div class="mdl-layout__content">
   <div class="main mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col"></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-shadow--4dp">
     <h3>Title</h3>
     <p>
      Cillum dolor esse sit incididunt velit eiusmod magna ad nostrud officia aute dolor dolor. Magna esse ullamco pariatur adipisicing consectetur eu commodo officia. Ex cillum consequat mollit minim elit est deserunt occaecat nisi amet. Quis aliqua nostrud Lorem occaecat sunt. Eiusmod quis amet ullamco aliquip dolore ut incididunt duis adipisicing. Elit consequat nisi eiusmod aute ipsum sunt veniam do est. Occaecat mollit aliquip ut proident consectetur amet ex dolore consectetur aliqua elit.
     </p>
     <p>
      Cillum dolor esse sit incididunt velit eiusmod magna ad nostrud officia aute dolor dolor. Magna esse ullamco pariatur adipisicing consectetur eu commodo officia. Ex cillum consequat mollit minim elit est deserunt occaecat nisi amet. Quis aliqua nostrud Lorem occaecat sunt. Eiusmod quis amet ullamco aliquip dolore ut incididunt duis adipisicing. Elit consequat nisi eiusmod aute ipsum sunt veniam do est. Occaecat mollit aliquip ut proident consectetur amet ex dolore consectetur aliqua elit.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` that contains the content that you want to overlay has its `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties set to `hidden` and `auto`, respectively. These styles are coming from the material CSS file you are using.

The fix is to override these rules so that the content that *overflows* the container is visible. We set `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to `visible`:

```
.overflow-fix.mdl-layout__content {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Note I also added an `overflow-fix` class to the `div` so that this fix is opt-in.

See updated [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld8ksLxc/2/).